# How to use Moq in unit test that calls another method in same class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Hi I am new to Moq framework and have some questions about how to use it. I will give an example and hope for answers.

I have two classes, an interface and and an implementation:

```
public class Vehicle{
   public string RegistrationNumber {get; set;}
   public long VehicleIdentifier { get; set; }
   public Tyre TyreSpecification { get; set; }
}

public class Tyre {
    public long NumberOfTyres {get; set;}
    public long TyreSize { get; set;}
}

public interface ISelecter {
   Vehicle GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber(string registrationNumber);
   Tyre GetTyreSpecification(long vehicleIdentifier);
}

public class Selecter : ISelecter
{
    public Vehicle GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber(string registrationNumber)
    {
        var vehicle = 'Database will give us the vehicle specification';

        //Then we do things with the vehicle object

        //Get the tyre specification
        vehicle.TyreSpecification = GetTyreSpecification(vehicle.VehicleIdentifier);

        return vehicle;

    }

    public Tyre GetTyreSpecification(long vehicleIdentifier)
    {
         var tyre = 'external manufacture system gets the tyre specification';

         //Then do thing with the tyre before returning the object


         return tyre;
    }
}
```

I want to write two tests for those methods. The problem is when I write the test for `GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber` I do not know how to mock the method call to `GetTyreSpecification`.

The test methods look like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class SelecterTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetTyreSpecification_test()
    {
        //Arrange
        var tyre = new Tyre { NumberOfTyres = 4, TyreSize = 18 };

        var mockSelecter = new Mock<ISelecter>();
        mockSelecter.SetUp(s=>s.GetTyreSpecification(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(tyre);

        //Act
        var tyreSpec = mockSelecter.Object.GetTyreSpecification(123456);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(tyreSpec.NumberOfTyres == 4 && tyreSpec.TyreSize == 18);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber_test()
    {
        //Arrange
        var vehicle= new Vehicle { VehicleIdentifier = 123456, RegistrationNumber = ABC123, TyreSpecification = new Tyre { Tyresize = 18, NumberOfTyres = 4 }};

        var mockSelecter = new Mock<ISelecter>();
        mockSelecter.SetUp(s=>s.GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber(It.IsAny<string>     ())).Returns(vehicle);

        //Act
        var vehicle = mockSelecter.Object.GetVehicleByregistrationNumber(123456);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(vehicle.Registrationnumber == "ABC123";
    }
}
```

In the test method `GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber_test` how do I mock the call to `getTyreSpecification`?

Comment: @Nkosi Your tests are good! Don't try to test more than what your stated test does - you shouldn't be testing anything more than getting a vehicle by the reg number. Any vehicle specific tests should be kept in their own test methods like you already have written above. Don't test more than one thing at a time.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to mock a method on the class you're trying to test. Mocking frameworks are used to replace the actual calls made to dependencies that your class takes in with fake calls so that you can focus on testing the behaviour of your class without being distracted by external dependencies that it has.

There are no external dependencies taken in by your `Selecter` class so you don't need to mock anything. I would always advocate not mocking if you don't have to and testing the actual code itself. Obviously, to keep your test atomic, you would need to mock calls to external dependencies if there were any.

Comment: I understand. But the GetTyresSpecification has stuff that I do not want to be executed and when I test the GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber This is a simplified version of the problem in the real application 7 calls to external system is made in the getTyreSpecification. Is it not possible to mock this method and only retrieve the data I want for the TyreSpecification?

Comment: You have 2 alternatives. You can either mock the external calls that happen within the `getTyreSpecification` method or you can pull that method out into its own class, wrapped in an interface, and inject the interface into your `Selecter` class. That would allow you to mock it.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answers. I mock the external calls. This means that I have duplicated code for my test of GetTyresSpecification method. One code snippet in the test method for GetTyresSpecification method and one code snippet in the GetVehicleByregistrationNumber method that do the exact same thing. Correct?

Comment: You shouldn't probably be trying to mock a method on the class you're trying to test but there are multiple valid reasons to. Imagine if one of your public method "A", which is extensively tested is called by another public method "B" from the same class. In this case you wouldn't be interested to write and maintain the same tests twice and you should focus on testing what makes B distinct instead of retesting A. In this case I would be far more interested to mock A and use a spy to test how B calls A.

Answer (score 37):

The focus on mocking the class under test has blinded you to the actual problem.

From the comments in the class under test...

> - 'Database will give us the vehicle specification'
> - 'external manufacture system gets the tyre specification'

you actually expose two dependencies that should be injected into the class.

For the purpose of explaining this answer lets say those dependencies looked like this.

```
public interface IDatabase {
    Vehicle GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber(string registrationNumber);
}

public interface IExternalManufactureSystem {
    Tyre GetTyreSpecification(long vehicleIdentifier);
}
```

That would mean that the `Selecter` would need to be refactored to expect those dependencies.

```
public class Selecter : ISelecter {
    private IDatabase database;
    private IExternalManufactureSystem externalManufactureSystem;

    public Selecter(IDatabase database, IExternalManufactureSystem externalManufactureSystem) {
        this.database = database;
        this.externalManufactureSystem = externalManufactureSystem;
    }

    public Vehicle GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber(string registrationNumber) {
        //'Database will give us the vehicle specification'
        var vehicle = database.GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber(registrationNumber);

        //Then we do things with the vehicle object

        //Get the tyre specification
        vehicle.TyreSpecification = GetTyreSpecification(vehicle.VehicleIdentifier);

        return vehicle;
    }

    public Tyre GetTyreSpecification(long vehicleIdentifier) {
        //'external manufacture system gets the tyre specification'
        var tyre = externalManufactureSystem.GetTyreSpecification(vehicleIdentifier);

        //Then do thing with the tyre before returning the object

        return tyre;
    }
}
```

From there it would then be a matter of mocking only the dependencies explicitly needed to test the behavior of the method under test.

`selecter.GetTyreSpecification` has no need to access the database so there is no reason to mock and inject it for the test.

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetTyreSpecification_test() {
    //Arrange
    var vehicleIdentifier = 123456;
    var expected = new Tyre { NumberOfTyres = 4, TyreSize = 18 };

    var mockSystem = new Mock<IExternalManufactureSystem>();
    mockSystem.Setup(s => s.GetTyreSpecification(vehicleIdentifier)).Returns(expected);

    var selecter = new Selecter(null, mockSystem.Object);

    //Act
    var actual = selecter.GetTyreSpecification(vehicleIdentifier);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

`selecter.GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber` however needs to be able to get the tyre specification from the other method so this test would need both dependencies mocked in order for it to be exercised to completion.

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber_test() {
    //Arrange
    var vehicleIdentifier = 123456;
    var registrationNumber = "ABC123";
    var tyre = new Tyre { TyreSize = 18, NumberOfTyres = 4 };
    var expected = new Vehicle {
        VehicleIdentifier = vehicleIdentifier,
        RegistrationNumber = registrationNumber,
        TyreSpecification = tyre
    };

    var mockSystem = new Mock<IExternalManufactureSystem>();
    mockSystem.Setup(s => s.GetTyreSpecification(vehicleIdentifier)).Returns(tyre);

    var mockDatabase = new Mock<IDatabase>();
    mockDatabase.Setup(s => s.GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber(registrationNumber)).Returns(expected);

    var selecter = new Selecter(mockDatabase.Object, mockSystem.Object);

    //Act
    var actual = selecter.GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber(registrationNumber);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(actual.RegistrationNumber == registrationNumber);
}
```

Now with that out of the way, if for example the `Selecter` class had the `GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber` as a `virtual` method,

```
public virtual Tyre GetTyreSpecification(long vehicleIdentifier) {
    //...code removed for brevity.
}
```

There is a way you can use moq to stub the subject under test and mock that method for testing. This is not always the best design and is considered a code smell. However there are situations where you will end up in this particular scenario.

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber_test2() {
    //Arrange
    var vehicleIdentifier = 123456;
    var registrationNumber = "ABC123";
    var tyre = new Tyre { TyreSize = 18, NumberOfTyres = 4 };
    var expected = new Vehicle {
        VehicleIdentifier = vehicleIdentifier,
        RegistrationNumber = registrationNumber,
        TyreSpecification = tyre
    };        

    var mockDatabase = new Mock<IDatabase>();
    mockDatabase.Setup(s => s.GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber(registrationNumber)).Returns(expected);

    var selecter = new Mock<Selecter>(mockDatabase.Object, null) {
        CallBase = true //So that base methods that are not setup can be called.
    }

    selecter.Setup(s => s.GetTyreSpecification(vehicleIdentifier)).Returns(tyre);

    //Act
    var actual = selecter.Object.GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber(registrationNumber);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(actual.RegistrationNumber == registrationNumber);
}
```

In the above example, when `selecter.Object.GetVehicleByRegistrationNumber(registrationNumber)` is called, the base `Selecter` wrapped by the mock will be called, which in turn will then call the mocked `GetTyreSpecification` that was overridden by the setup on the mocked subject under test.

You tend to see this when testing abstract classes with implemented members that have dependencies on abstract members.

Answer (score 6):

In general we use mocks for external dependencies/other object/interface calls being used within our class for which we will write unit tests. So when you are writing test for one of your function which internally makes a call to another function within the same class you don't have to mock that function call. However in the internal function if you are making call to an external interface then you will have to mock the external interface instance and write your unit test with expected result